# python gensim word2vec gives typeerror TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len() on custom dataclass

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, gensim, training-data

I am trying to get word2vec to work in python3, however as my dataset is too large to easily fit in memory I am loading it via an iterator (from zip files). However when I run it I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "WordModel.py", line 85, in <module>
    main()
  File "WordModel.py", line 15, in main
    word2vec = gensim.models.Word2Vec(data,workers=cpu_count())
  File "/home/thijser/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 783, in __init__
    fast_version=FAST_VERSION)
  File "/home/thijser/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/base_any2vec.py", line 759, in __init__
    self.build_vocab(sentences=sentences, corpus_file=corpus_file, trim_rule=trim_rule)
  File "/home/thijser/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/base_any2vec.py", line 936, in build_vocab
    sentences=sentences, corpus_file=corpus_file, progress_per=progress_per, trim_rule=trim_rule)
  File "/home/thijser/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 1591, in scan_vocab
    total_words, corpus_count = self._scan_vocab(sentences, progress_per, trim_rule)
  File "/home/thijser/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 1576, in _scan_vocab
    total_words += len(sentence)
TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

Here is the code:

```
import zipfile
import os
from ast import literal_eval

from lxml import etree
import io
import gensim

from multiprocessing import cpu_count


def main():
    data = TrainingData("/media/thijser/Data/DataSets/uit2")
    print(len(data))
    word2vec = gensim.models.Word2Vec(data,workers=cpu_count())
    word2vec.save('word2vec.save')




class TrainingData:

    size=-1

    def __init__(self, dirname):
        self.data_location = dirname

    def __len__(self):
        if self.size<0: 

            for zipfile in self.get_zips_in_folder(self.data_location): 
                for text_file in self.get_files_names_from_zip(zipfile):
                    self.size=self.size+1
        return self.size            

    def __iter__(self): #might not fit in memory otherwise
        yield self.get_data()

    def get_data(self):


        for zipfile in self.get_zips_in_folder(self.data_location): 
            for text_file in self.get_files_names_from_zip(zipfile):
                yield self.preproccess_text(text_file)


    def stripXMLtags(self,text):

        tree=etree.parse(text)
        notags=etree.tostring(tree, encoding='utf8', method='text')
        return notags.decode("utf-8") 

    def remove_newline(self,text):
        text.replace("\\n"," ")
        return text

    def preproccess_text(self,text):
        text=self.stripXMLtags(text)
        text=self.remove_newline(text)

        return text




    def get_files_names_from_zip(self,zip_location):
        files=[]
        archive = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_location, 'r')

        for info in archive.infolist():
            files.append(archive.open(info.filename))

        return files

    def get_zips_in_folder(self,location):
       zip_files = []
       for root, dirs, files in os.walk(location):
            for name in files:
                if name.endswith((".zip")): 
                    filepath=root+"/"+name
                    zip_files.append(filepath)

       return zip_files

main()


for d in data:
    for dd in d :
        print(type(dd))
```

Does show me that dd is of the type string and contains the correct preprocessed strings (with length somewhere between 50 and 5000 words each).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update after discussion:**

Your `TrainingData` class `__iter__()` function isn't providing a generator which returns each text in turn, but rather a generator which returns a single *other* generator. (There's one too many levels of `yield`.) That's not what `Word2Vec` is expecting.

Changing the body of your `__iter__()` method to simply...

```
return self.get_data()
```

...so that `__iter__()` is a synonym for your `get_data()`, and just returns the same text-by-text generator that `get_data()` does, should help.

**Original answer:**

You're not showing the `TrainingData.preproccess_text()` (sic) method, referenced inside `get_data()`, which is what is actually creating the data `Word2Vec` is processing. And, it's that data that's generating the error.

`Word2Vec` requires its `sentences` corpus be an *iterable sequence* (for which a generator would be appropriate) where each individual item is a *list-of-string-tokens*.

From that error, it looks like the individual items in your `TrainingData` sequence may themselves be generators, rather than lists with a readable `len()`.

(Separately, if perchance you're choosing to using generators there because the individual texts may be very very long, be aware that gensim `Word2Vec` and related classes only train on individual texts with a length up to 10000 word-tokens. Any words past the 10000th will be silently ignored. If that's a concern, your source texts should be pre-broken into individual texts of 10000 tokens or fewer.)

Comment: I added the missing code, the output of preproccess_text is of type "str" changing the line 'return text' in preproccess_text into         return [text] changes the error to TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: The code, as shown, is still giving the same error/stack for `TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()` as shown in the original question? What does `iter(data).next()[0:10]` show?

Comment: yes the error is still the same. If I call   data = TrainingData("/media/thijser/Data/DataSets/uit2")
    print(iter(data).next()[0:10]) I get the error   File "WordModel.py", line 84, in <module>
    main()
  File "WordModel.py", line 14, in main
    print(iter(data).next()[0:10])
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: for d in data:
        for dd in d :
            print(dd) does however give a list of strings containing the actual training data (with lengths of around 50-5000 words each).

Comment: Aha, in Py3 it may need to be `next(iter(data))` to get the 1st element - but I see the problem now - your definition of `__iter__()` returns a generator that can only `yield` one element, which is itself a generator. I've prepended an update to the answer to help.